# Hello. I'm making a lyrics app which can also play the music of the lyrics

Tags: android

what I'm trying to do is add 1 button that will play and stop the music. is it possible to loop them like 1st click play then 2nd click stop 3rd click will start from beginning and 4th stops again and so on?

based on my search on google it's something like this? sorry if noob question

```
public void playtd(View view) {
    if(!td.isPlaying()) {
        td.start();
    }
    else if(td.isPlaying()) {
        td.pause();
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the second condition (waste of CPU cycles). Just use `else`. Also, I'd check it in revese (to save firing a **not** operator). You might also have to set the `td.isPlayng` state, depending on the implementation of the td object.

Comment: I'm really sorry but I really don't understand a thing of what you're saying. It would help very much if you show me an example if that is not to much to ask.

you can say i'm a lvl 1 here if that's the lowest you can get

@Rotwang

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
MediaPlayer td;
boolean isPrepared;
public void prepareMediaPlayer(Uri yourTrackUri){
// call this on initialization of your mediaplayer
        sMRMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, uri);
        sPrepared = true;

}
public void playtd(View view) {

     if (!isPrepared) {
            prepareMediaPlayer(Uri yourTrackUri)
        }
       if(!td.isPlaying()) {
          td.start();
        else {
         // reprepare mediaplayer
          td = MediaPlayer.create(Context, uriToUrFile);
          isPrepared = true;
       }
    } else { // stop playing instead of pause, stop will start playing next time u play from beginning
        td.stop();
    }

    void releaseMediaPlayer() {
    if (td!= null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "MediaPlayer is released.");
        td.reset();
        td.release();
        td= null;
        isPrepared = false;
    }
}
```

call releaseMediaPlayer once done with all play and stop stuff (may be on destroy etc.)
initialize mediaplayer by passing track uri to prepareMediaPlayer
add try catch, wherever needed

Comment: yes, I said you need to maintain such flag for `td`.
whenever u Release media player make it false and true when initialized.

Comment: im a noob.. can you show me example? if it's not asking too much

Comment: Thanks for the help!